# Designing specific UI in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I want to create a UI in java using swings and awt such that :

```
**** BUTTON1 , BUTTON2,BUTTON3, BUTTON4, BUTTON5 **** (in a row )
***** GRID OF SIZE 20 X 20 ****** (next)

frame.setSize(1000,700);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    smile = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/RISHABH/Desktop/PP/MineSweeper/sm.png");
    sad = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/RISHABH/Desktop/PP/MineSweeper/smb.png");
    mine = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/RISHABH/Desktop/PP/MineSweeper/mine.png");

    panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    smiley.setIcon(smile);
    Dimension d = new Dimension(30,20);
    smiley.setPreferredSize(d);//.setSize(30, 20);

    panel1.add(timer);
    panel1.add(score);
    panel1.add(smiley);
    panel1.validate();
    //frame.add(smiley,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    //smiley.addActionListener(this);
    //Button grid
    buttons = new JButton[nrows][ncols];
    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(nrows,ncols));
    for(int i=0;i<nrows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<ncols;j++){
            buttons[i][j] = new JButton();
            buttons[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            grid.add(buttons[i][j]);

        }
    }
    panel2.add(grid,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //frame.add(grid,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(panel1);
    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

i created two panels ..
1st panel was added with all 3 buttons with layout set as BorderLayout 
2nd panel contained the grid .. 
and then added the two panels to the frame which has the layout border layout

but buttons are not added   and the grid appears small ... when I click that grid button it expands ..

Can anybody help me to create this UI ? I am new to java . Please help.

Comment: @Dragondraikk :  Can you pls see to it .. ?

Comment: From @CSCH (still not enough rep to comment) : *If your not stuck with having to use swing and awt, you can try Java's new SceneBuilder. Its very much like visual basic in the sense that you have several components that you can simply draw and drop on your UI and refer to each component in your java program through a variable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but buttons are not added

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
...
frame.add(panel1);
frame.add(panel2);
```

You are using a BorderLayout. You can't add to components to the CENTER, only the last component added will be displayed. Try:

```
frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(panel2.CENTER);
```

> and the grid appears small

```
frame.setSize(1000,700);
```

Don't hardcode the size. Let the layout manager do its job by invoking the `pack()` method:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Don't har